# How to step through Swing app in Intellij

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, trace, step-through

I am new to Intellij and am running a GUI app and wanted to know if there was a better way to trace execution than to run through debug mode and click through each line of code. I only want to see each function call and have it jump between functions in the IDE when I interact with the GUI.

Comment: Break points are the key. Use break points to stop and inspect program state when an event occurs. The other thing to do is to use proper MVC code separation which will allow you to debug your logic (the model) *separate* from the view (the GUI).

Comment: this is an entirely new project i imported and i should clarify i wanted to be able to interact with the GUI menu, and see whatever is being called in the code without setting breakpoint since i wouldnt know where to set them currently @HovercraftFullOfEels

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ IDEA debugger has the option to log the breakpoints without stopping. You can put the [logging breakpoints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byGlj.png) (**Suspend** disabled, **Log** enabled) where needed and use your app while watching the logs in the IDE console.